# get all single and multiline comment in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi Can anyone please help get all the single line and multiline comment in a given javascript string using regex.

Idea is to replace the single and multiline comment with empty quotes. so that I get the valid code from the string.

I am looking for a solution in javascript with regex.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989315/regex-for-match-replacing-javascript-comments-both-multiline-and-inline

Comment: _"Idea is to replace the single and multiline comment with empty quotes."_ - So `alert('test'); /* a test */` will be become `alert('test'); ""`? Or do you mean you want to replace comments with an empty string? **Please show a sample input with corresponding desired output.** _"so that I get the valid code from the string."_ - But JS comments _are_ valid within JS...