# How do I remove ONLY JavaScript comments that start with "// "?

Tags: javascript, php, regex, comments

To clarify first, I already have a compression tool that successfully compresses EVERYTHING else so I don't need a long complicated `preg_replace` regex, just a simple `preg_replace` or `str_replace` rule will do.

I ONLY want to remove JavaScript comments that start with "// " (including the space so I don't erase URLs) up until the new line. THAT'S IT! Once again, I don't need to replace /* */ or any other variations as I have a script that does that already; the only thing it's missing is this one feature so I want to clean up the input with this first, then hand it over to the script.

Here are screenshots with examples of comments I would like to remove:

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

I would really appreciate help with this! :-) THANKS!

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/4227915

Comment: Using PHP or JavaScript?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989315/regex-for-match-replacing-javascript-comments-both-multiline-and-inline but it seems easier to use one that is already written... And hopefully you have a test with a string that has a url to make sure you do not remove it.

Comment: It isn't a trivial task to do that with regex, in particular because `//` can be inside a string.

Comment: You can try https://regex101.com/r/cQ0dL8/1

Comment: I don't want to replace the text with a blank, I want to REMOVE THE ENTIRE LINE. hope that helps.

Comment: So, try this: _https://regex101.com/r/cQ0dL8/2_ .. The idea is the same

Comment: hey washington guedes how do I convert that into a preg_replace or str_replace command?

Comment: Do it like @PedroPinheiro did in his answer.. just change this line `$re = "[^\n]*\/\/[^\n]*";`

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$re = "~\\n? */{2,} .*~"; 
$str = "text\n\n/*\ntext\n*\n    //example1\n    //example2\n\ntext\n\n//   example 3"; 
$subst = ""; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

The regex matches two or more `/` following by a space like you asked in the question. When you replace it will erase the whole line or until the spaces and line breaks that were

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nT1nO6/3)

Comment: If you use a delimiter other than / for your expression, you won't have to escape the delimiter, such as `'~// .*$~'` will match slash slash space followed by anything to the end of the line.

Comment: YIKES! I tried this suggestion and it deletes almost everything leaving just the following in the html:

<!DOCTYPE html><html class="no-overflow-y" xmlns="http:<head/>

Comment: I don't want to replace the text with a blank, I want to REMOVE THE ENTIRE LINE. hope that helps...

Comment: @Kevin, sorry about that, I forgot about the URLs. I updated the answer now with the correct regex.

Comment: hey pedro, okay going to try it and let you know

Comment: hmm, you and the other guy have slightly different results. can you tell me what's the difference between: 

THIS ~\\n? */{2,} .*~
AND THIS /^\h*\/\/.*$/m

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a regex with the multi-lined [modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), `m`,

```
/^\h*\/\/.*$/m
```

This will find any lines that start with a `//` regardless of the whitespace preceding it. Anything after the first `//` will be removed until the end of that line.

Regex101 Demo: https://regex101.com/r/tN7nW9/2

You should include your data in the future as a string (not image) so users can run tests on it.

PHP Usage:

```
echo preg_replace('/^\h*\/\/.*$/m', '', $string);
```

PHP Demo: https://eval.in/430182

Comment: hmm, you and the other guy have slightly different results. can you tell me what's the difference between 

THIS ~\\n? */{2,} .*~
AND THIS /^\h*\/\/.*$/m

Comment: That looks like it says an optional new line, any amount of white spaces until two or more `/` characters then anything. Which could be dangerous. My regex is going line by line requiring the line start `//` (regardless of white space) and if so replacing the whole line with nothing. Again if you include your actual data this would be much easier, can just run regex101 with expressions.