# php remove empty single comment

Tags: php, regex

I have code like this

```
function get_id(){
   return 1;
   //
}
```

I want to remove all `//` inside the source code, but only those stand by it own, on a newline just like the example here. Nothing much nothing more. How can I do it?

Comment: Are you removing it with a text editor or with php?

Comment: What IDE/editor are you using?

Comment: Do you intend to also remove the linebreak, together with the line?

Comment: Maybe this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32462878/how-do-i-remove-only-javascript-comments-that-start-with/32467204#32467204, would be useful for you to start with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search using this regex:

```
^\s*\/\/\s*$
```

and replace by empty string.

If using PHP you can use `\h` (horizontal space) instead of `\s`:

```
$code = preg_replace('~^\h*//\h*$~m', '', $code);
```