# php regex remove inline comment only

Tags: php, regex

I have simple code look like this

```
function session(){
   return 1; // this default value for session
}
```

I need regex or code to remove the comment `// this is default value for session`, And only remove this type of comment, which starts by a space or two or more, then `//`, then a newline after it.

All other types of comment and cases are ignored.

Comment: Couldn't you modify the answer from the last question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34683699/3933332 ?

Comment: This is distinguished question. This will be good for other to study the process part by part rather than throw in a 200 character regex heaven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***UPDATED*** <sup>(1)</sup>

> And only remove this type of comment, which starts by a space or two or more, then //, then a newline after it

Try this one:

[**regex101 1**](https://regex101.com/r/cI9iY9/3)

[**PHP Fiddle 1**](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/rjh3-m1xg) -*hit "run" or F9 to see the result*

```
/\s+\/\/[^\n]+/m
```

- `\s+` *starts by a space or two or more*
- `\/\/` *the escaped `//`*
- `[^\n]+` *anything except a new line*

---

**UPDATE:** to make sure -*kinda*-this only applied to code lines, we can make use of the [*lookbehind*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) <sup>(2)</sup> regex to check if there is a semicolon `;` before the space[s] and the comment slashes `//`, so the regex will be this:

[**regex101 2**](https://regex101.com/r/cI9iY9/5)

[**PHP Fiddle 2**](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/q4cw-kuv7)

```
/(?<=;)\s+\/\/[^\n]+/m
```

where `(?<=;)` is the lookbehind which basically tells the engine to *look behind* and check if there's a `;` before it then match.

### -----------------------------------------------------------------------

<sup>(1)</sup> *The* `preg_replace` *works globally, no need for the* `g` *flag*

<sup>(2)</sup> *The lookbehind is not supported in javascript*

Comment: error preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 'g'. I run it like this $html = preg_replace('/\s+\/\/[^\n]+/gm', '', $html);

Comment: @angry_kiwi, my fault, `preg_replace()` just works globally this why it doesn't need the `g` flag, check this http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/ts8s-fywa -*hit run or F9 to execute and see the result*-, I apologize I'll update my answer

Comment: @angry_kiwi, you may consider using the regex with the lookbehind way http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/q4cw-kuv7

Comment: The `m` pattern modifier is useless if you don't have any start of line or end of line metacharacters (`^` or `$`).

Answer (score 0):

A purely regex solution would look something like this:

```
$result = preg_replace('#^(.*?)\s+//.*$#m', '\1', $source);
```

but that would still be wrong because you could get trapped by something like this:

```
$str = "This is a string // that has a comment inside";
```

A more robust solution would be to completely rewrite the php code using [token_get_all()](http://php.net/token_get_all) to actually parse the PHP code into tokens that you can then selectively remove when you re-emit the code:

```
foreach(token_get_all($source) as $token)
{
    if(is_array($token))
    {
        if($token[0] != T_COMMENT || substr($token[1] != '//', 0, 3))
            echo $token[1];
    }
    else
        echo $token;
}
```