# insert variable as text in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to pass a variable as text or somehow to make above function to work:

```
var title = "Hello World";
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {code: "var param1='"+title+"'; var param2='value2'; "}, function(){ /*some code*/ });
```

When I execute above function it not pass `title` to `param1`, it must define `param1` as `title`. Because `title` is dynamic, it can be diffrent, so I really need to know how can pass my title variable.

If I change code like this :

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {code: "var param1='Hello World!'; var param2='value2'; "}, function(){ /*some code*/ });
```

than it works perfect

Comment: What is the value of `tabId`? Also, in case you didn't know: [`chrome.tabs.executeScript`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript) will **not** work in Content scripts.

Comment: i am not sure that i understand the question, can you give an example of what output you desire from this?

Comment: Above code works good... but param1 value is undefined.. because it not pass.

Comment: @user It does not pass, so it does not work. Add `alert(location.href)` in the code, to verify that the code is correctly injected, in the right tab.

Comment: it works...I checked!  but it pass param1 as undefenited. IF I change code like this than it work perfect as I want:

chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {code: "var param1='Hello World'; var param2='value2'; "}, function(){ /*some code*/ });

Comment: @user1267305 That is impossible. Does `param1` **really** contain "Hello World", or does it also contain something else? Show your exact code, because I'm pretty sure that the problem is caused by something else.

Comment: @RobW maybe you right.... it contain html code, this value can contain tags. If so, then how do I fix it ?  Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `title` string contains quotes, newlines or backslashes. These characters have to be escaped:

```
var title = 'Your string was here, with a "quote" etc.';

// Escape each special character:
title = title.replace(/[\\"']/g, '\\$&') /* Backslash and quotes */
             .replace(/\n/g, '\\n')      /* Newlines             */
             .replace(/\r/g, '\\r')      /* Carriage returns     */
             .replace(/\t/g, '\\t')      /* Tabs                 */
             .replace(/\b/g, '\\f')      /* Backspace            */
             .replace(/\f/g, '\\b');     /* Form feed            */

chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {code: "var param1='"+title+"'; var param2='value2'; "}, function(){ /*some code*/ })
```

Comment: I actually hard trouble with this, but instead compiled my code with closure compiler, with whitespace only compilation, and, then removed all newlines.

Comment: This code may throw errors for you if you're trying to clean javascript code to execute. You can to replace newlines, carriage returns, backspace and form feeds with a space character or no char ('')

Comment: @DevinGRhode "Cleaning JS code to execute"? Can you give an example? The answer will never fail for the circumstances as described by the question. Is your input a valid string? E.g. no unescaped line breaks before a string literal is terminated.

Comment: I have a live extension update system, so I fetch a js file over the network, store in localStorage, and execute. The code is closure-compiled, which outputs newlines every ~500 chars.

Comment: If you're googling and have my scenario, where you need to eval javascript, checkout my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13775229/565877

Comment: @DevinGRhode Can you give an example where the above code fails?

Comment: I can't. I'm sure it does what it's supposed to just fine, but as I was googling, it was almost my answer, but not quite.

Comment: In my scenario, my js file simply had a newline, but this was replace by `\n` and `eval('\\n var = 22;')` is not valid js code.

Comment: @DevinGRhode In that case, the input string was directly passed to eval. You don't need to replace any characters at all.